# How to insert POST data into Django model using rest-frameWork

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am trying to POST data to my Django app using Django rest-frameWork...

My view is :

```
@csrf_view_exempt
class subscriptionsList(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        key = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('appKey', None)
        keyData = app.objects.filter(appKey=key).exists()         

        if keyData == True:
            serializer = PostSubscriptionDetailSerializer(data=request.DATA)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py : 
 `url(r'^subscribe/$',subscriptionsList,name='subscriptions-list'),`

serializer.py

```
class PostSubscriptionDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = subscriptions
        fields = ('subAppName','subStoreName','subTagName','emailID')
```

Can someone tell me how to POST data using Django REST-frameWork...

Comment: It's not really clear what the question is.  I think you're asking how update a Subscription instance, given the post data.  If that's the case you need to be getting the subscription instance and then doing something like... `PostSubscriptionDetailSerializer(subscription, data=request.DATA)`

Comment: Yes i want to insert DATA using POST in my Django model....through rest-frameWork...

Comment: It's still not clear what your problem is.